# Victory: Animating Circular Progress Bar - not rendering chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I'm working to use Victory's charting library with React to render a Animating Circular Progress bar like so:

https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/animating-circular-progress-bar

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {VictoryPie, VictoryAnimation, VictoryLabel} from 'victory';




class YourRatings2 extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      percent: 25, data: this.getData(0)
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let percent = 25;
  }

  getData(percent) {
    return [{x: 1, y: percent}, {x: 2, y: 100 - percent}];
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <section className="YourRatings">
          <h2>Core Skills</h2>

            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="100%" height="100%">
                <VictoryPie
                  animate={{duration: 1000}}
                  width={400} height={400}
                  data={this.state.data}
                  innerRadius={120}
                  cornerRadius={3}
                  labels={() => null}
                  style={{
                    data: { fill: (d) => {
                      const color = d.y > 30 ? "green" : "red";
                      return d.x === 1 ? color : "transparent";
                    }
                   }
                  }}
                />
                <VictoryAnimation duration={1000} data={this.state}>
                  {(newProps) => {
                    return (
                      <VictoryLabel
                        textAnchor="middle" verticalAnchor="middle"
                          x={200} y={200}
                        text={`${Math.round(newProps.percent)}%`}
                        style={{ fontSize: 45 }}
                      />
                    );
                  }}
                </VictoryAnimation>
              </svg>
            </div>

        </section>
      );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourRatings2);
```

Unfortunately, this is only rendering the text, not the full graph. see:

[image]

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this library but the example that you gave has an interval function to update `this.state.data` with the new percentage. You are setting initial percentage to 0 and not updating.

Setting the interval like the example or setting the initial state with the example below should fix the problem.

**Example**

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    percent: 25,
    data: this.getData(25)
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it had no effect. In the render method, if I output `this.state.data` I am seeing valid values: `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{x: 1, y: 25}
1
:
{x: 2, y: 75}
length
:
2`

Comment: @AnApprentice I'm sorry but can you please double check? I tried the code you posted in the editable example the page you gave and if you set the percentage like I said it works just fine.

Comment: I think I might have a height/width issue which is preventing me from even seeing the PieChart, I'm trying to understand how to shrink it down to 60px... will report back if I can figure it out :)

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the prop standalone={false} to VictoryPie

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Giving us some explanation and code examples will improve it.